# What are the actual sizes of AdMob banners used on iPads and iPhones

Tags: ios, banner-ads, admob

The AdMob page states the following "Smart Banner" Sizes.

> Three ad heights (in density-independent pixels [dp]) are implemented in smart banners:

```
Ad height   Screen height
32dp        ≤400dp
50dp        > 400dp and ≤ 720dp
90dp        > 720dp
```

It isn't clear what that means for the various iOS devices in various orientations. I am looking at converting from iAd at the moment and am faced with resizing from the iAD 66 pixel high banner, but it isn't clear whether I am going to lose or gain space.

I see the ad height is defined in "dp"s based on the screen height "dp"s, but I am not really sure what this means.

Comment: You don't have to use the smart banners do you? I think there are fixed size banners. If I remember correctly, one for iPhone was like 320x40

Comment: I will want to use for the iPad in landscape.